# Правило для Nginx (RewriteRule)

Tags: nginx

Сервер Nginx слушает два домена в секции server {
server_name domain1.com, domain2.com;

Мне нужно сделать различия в паре файлов
Как, например, сделать так, чтобы для domain2.com
вместо /test.php запрос шел на /domain2/test.php
По типу RewriteRule в htaccess

Comment: Сделать две секции сервер и не мучать nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($http_host ~* "^domain2.com?$") {rewrite ^/test.php?$ /domain2/test.php;}
```